# Angular Form validation not working, submit button not getting enabled

Tags: html, jquery, angular, forms

The Angular form in the Submit Button is greyed out even though all fields are filled in, not sure what could be wrong. On filling up all the fields the button is not getting enabled and as per the css it should be turned green. Either of it is not working. Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated.

This is my code as for the contactus.component.html

```
<form id="form_query" [formGroup]="formdata"  (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()" data-empty="" action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <input type="first_name"  formControlName="first_name" placeholder="Enter your First Name:" required>

      <input type="last_name"   formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Enter your Last Name:" required>

      <textarea rows="4" cols="70"   formControlName="desc" placeholder="Enter your Description:" required ></textarea>

     <input type="email"  placeholder="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address :" required>

       <input type="phone"  formControlName="phone"  placeholder="Enter your Phone Number :" required>

    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Your Query" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</form>
```

contactus.component.ts file is as below:

```
function submitState(el) {

    var $form = $(el),
        $requiredInputs = $form.find('input:required'),
        $submit = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');

    $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $requiredInputs.keyup(function () {

      $form.data('empty', 'false');

      $requiredInputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
          $form.data('empty', 'true');
        }
      });

      if ($form.data('empty') === 'true') {
        $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('title', 'fill in all required fields');
      } else {
        $submit.removeAttr('disabled').attr('title', 'click to submit');
      }
    });
  }
  // apply to each form element individually
  submitState('#form_query');
```

contactus.component.css is as below:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

form input:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background: #5cb85c;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: background 600ms;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:disabled {
  background: #555;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: Might I ask you why did you prefer to use jQuery in an angular application?

Comment: Was trying to follow this :
https://jsfiddle.net/bno08c44/4/

Comment: I see, but to be honest, there is no need to use jQuery to handle any form operation in angular. Angular reactive forms includes almost all the features, including form validations.  Please check the documentations on reactive forms, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. They cover how to use reactive forms well. I think ionut-t's answer explains what needs to be done in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Never a good idea to use jQuery inside an Angular project.
You should check the Angular documentation for forms to properly understand how they work.

Anyway, this is the right implementation for the reactive forms:

```js
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
        first_name: [null, Validators.required],
        last_name: [null, Validators.required],
        desc: [null, Validators.required],
        email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        phone: [null, Validators.required]
    });
}

onClickSubmit() {
  if(this.form.invalid) return;

  // do stuff
}
```

```html
  <button [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to forms modules in angular instead of using it as jQuery
[Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the reactive forms module is correctly imported in your app.module. More information [here (angular doc)](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).
By the way your first two input types are incorrect : [MZN input type doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-validation-wkfewd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Update:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Your Query" disabled="disabled">
```

To

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Your Query" disabled="disabled">
```

For a better solution in Angular:

[valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) : observable that emits an event every time the value of the control changes

So you need to add the formgroup valueChanges Observable to ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formdata.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (
        this.formdata.controls['first_name'].value != '' &&
        this.formdata.controls['last_name'].value != '' &&
        this.formdata.controls['desc'].value != '' &&
        this.formdata.controls['email'].value != '' &&
        this.formdata.controls['phone'].value != ''
      ) {
        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Getting this error: 
Error: src/app/contactus/contactus.component.ts:34:8 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

34        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');

Comment: @Learner hi, i updated my answer